# Using the observer class in Java

Tags: java

So I am supposed to make my class Belt observable by two observers, but I'm not sure how to do this and the guides I have found so far confuse me. The issue I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around is where to put these observable methods. I am having this issue because the problem asks me to use an instance of the class PlateEvent as the object that describes the change. Any help would be great, and here are the question and code:

You need to modify this implementation of Belt so that it extends java.util.Observable. Whenever a plate is placed on or removed from the belt, you should arrange to notify any registered observers of the change. Use an instance of PlateEvent (described below) as the object that describes the change.

PlateEvent defines the object that will be passed as the second parameter to the update() method when observers of Belt are notified that a plate has been placed or removed. Within PlateEvent is an enumeration called EventType that defines two symbols: PLATE_PLACED and PLATE_REMOVED. A PlateEvent object encapsulates one of these two types, a reference to the plate that was placed or removed, and the position where this occurs. You should read through PlateEvent.java to make sure you understand the class and how to construct new instances, but you should not have any need to modify the code there.

```
package a6adept;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import comp401.sushi.Plate;

public class Belt extends java.util.Observable {

    Plate[] belt;

    public Belt(int size) {
        if (size <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal belt size");
        }

        belt = new Plate[size];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return belt.length;
    }

    public Plate getPlateAtPosition(int position) {
        return belt[correct_position(position)];
    }

    public void setPlateAtPosition(Plate plate, int position) throws BeltPlateException {
        if (plate == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (getPlateAtPosition(position) != null) {
            throw new BeltPlateException(position, plate, this);
        } else {
            belt[correct_position(position)] = plate; 
        }
    }

    public void clearPlateAtPosition(int position) {
        belt[correct_position(position)] = null;
    }

    public Plate removePlateAtPosition(int position) {
        Plate plate_at_position = getPlateAtPosition(position);
        if (plate_at_position == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        clearPlateAtPosition(position);
        return plate_at_position;
    }

    public int setPlateNearestToPosition(Plate plate, int position) throws BeltFullException {
        for (int offset=0; offset < getSize(); offset++) {
            try {
                setPlateAtPosition(plate, position+offset);
                return position+offset;
            } catch (BeltPlateException e) {
            }
        }
        throw new BeltFullException(this);
    }

    public void rotate() {
        Plate last_plate = belt[getSize()-1];
        for (int i=getSize()-1; i>0; i--) {
            belt[i] = belt[i-1];
        }
        belt[0] = last_plate;
    }

    private int correct_position(int position) {
        if (position < 0) {
            return ((position%getSize())+getSize())%getSize();
        }
        return position%getSize();
    }

}


package a6adept;

import comp401.sushi.Plate;

public class PlateEvent {
    public enum EventType {PLATE_PLACED, PLATE_REMOVED};

    private EventType type;
    private Plate plate;
    private int position;

    public PlateEvent(EventType type, Plate plate, int position) {
        this.type = type;
        this.plate = plate;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public EventType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public  Plate getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time a plate is placed on or removed from the belt, you need to construct a `PlateEvent` object with appropriate attributes, and then call `notifyObservers(plateEvent)`.

You don't need to do anything else, since `Observable` provides the mechanism for other objects to register to observe your object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says your `Belt extends Observable`. The rest comes form the javadoc:

```
/**
Adds an observer to the set of observers for this object, provided that it is not the same as some observer already in the set.
*/
public void addObserver(Observer o)
```

So you need to add them to a set. Why? So you can tell them when something comes on the belt. How? Look at its javadoc:

```
/**
This method is called whenever the observed object is changed. An application calls an Observable object's notifyObservers method to have all the object's observers notified of the change.
*/
void update(Observable o, Object arg)
```

So you need to call update when something changes. What? Read the question: send it an event telling it what happened? How? The core java API doesn't know what your problem is it nets you send an `Object` type which is your event which is something you created in your app to represent the event being passed to signal the change.